How is a $\pi/2$ pulse implemented with a transmon qubit?
I've become roughly familiar with transmon qubits like those mentioned in this post. I also am aware that in order to use qubits in an effective way we have to control the quantum states of the bits (and entanglements).
Mathematically, the simplest form of this would be to implement a $\pi/2$ pulse to place a qubit into a state that is a coherent quantum admixture of the ground and excited state. The basic mathematics of this is here.
My question is, how is this typically implemented in a real transmon system? I am envisioning something like an RF line adjacent to the qubit (which is probably deposited on a silicon substrate or something). I suppose you can send the RF down that line at the qubit resonant frequency for a specific time to give the desired effect.
How do the details of the circuit and the geometry of the RF fields come into play here?
To explore the simplest operation of a qubit I guess I would want to know the implementation for the following operations:

put the qubit in the excited state
put the qubit in the ground state
take the qubit from an excited (ground) state to an admixture state like $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|g\rangle \pm |e\rangle)$
take the admixed state and put it back in the excited (ground) state.

